# Parsing json 2 levels down with JsonSlurper - groovy

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I've json response that I parsed it and looked at its keyset, like below . It only gives me 3 keysets. Why is it only making key-value pairs of 3 keysets? How do I retrieve values of fields that are two or more levels down?

Json looks like this( which is in `content` variable)

```
{  
   "seatbid":[  
      {  
         "bid":[  
            {  
               "id":"1",
               "impid":"1",
               "price":3.5999999046325684,
               "nurl":"abc.com",
               "adomain":[  
                  "zagg.com",
                  "zagg.com"
               ],
               "iurl":"abc.com",
               "crid":"30364.s320x50m",
               "h":0,
               "w":0
            }
         ],
         "group":0
      }
   ],
   "cur":"USD",
   "nbr":0
}
```

The I parsed and did a keyset check like this:

```
def RespSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def RespJson = RespSlurper.parseText(content)
log.info(RespJson.keySet())
log.info(RespJson.values())
log.info(RespJson.get("seatbid"))
```

The response from above `log.info`  is

```
Mon Jan 12 16:12:25 EST 2015:INFO:1
Mon Jan 12 16:12:25 EST 2015:INFO:[nbr, seatbid, cur]
Mon Jan 12 16:22:47 EST 2015:INFO:[0, [{group=0, bid=[{w=0, id=1, nurl=abc.com, price=3.5999999046325684, crid=30364.s320x50m, adomain=[zagg.com, zagg.com], impid=1, iurl=abc.com}]}], USD]
Mon Jan 12 16:22:47 EST 2015:INFO:[{group=0, bid=[{w=0, id=1, nurl=abc.com, price=3.5999999046325684, crid=30364.s320x50m, adomain=[zagg.com, zagg.com], impid=1, iurl=abc.com}]}]
```

How do I get values of other fields say `impid` ?

```
 log.info(RespJson.get("impid"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is parsed to a HashMap where JSONArray's will be parsed to lists inside the content map.

```
RespJson.seatbid[0].bid[0].impid
```

should give the first `impid` of first `bid` of first `seatbid`.

Log and have a look at the response after parsing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry for my late reply , I was testing this stuff. How do I `log.info` if `seatbid[0].bid[0].impid` is being added to `RespJson` dynamically. I tried to do this `def RespNode= "RespJson"+"."+ assertionKey` `log.info(RespNode)` where `assertionKey` that has a value of `seatbid[0].bid[0].impid` is added dynamically to `RespJson` . The result of `log.info(RespNode)` is `RespJson.seatbid[0].bid[0].impid` and not the value.

Comment: Got it working, used this `Eval.me('RespJson',RespJson, "def v='$RespNode'")` and then `log.info(v)` which solved the issue that I explained in my comment.

Comment: Actually the comment that I added above is not working as expected.    and I am still looking for answer.